# Can we do all the things which we can do in BizTalk using SSIS

Tags: ssis, biztalk

I have been using SSIS for a while, and I have never came across BizTalk.

One of the data migration project we are doing, also consists of BizTalk, apart from SSIS.

I just wondered what is the need of `BizTalk`, if we already have a `SSIS` ETL tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SSIS is well suited for bulk ETL batch options where you're transfering data between a SQL Server and

- Another RDBMS
- Excel
- A **simple** CSV file
- You do not need row by row processing
- Your mapping is primarily data type conversion mapping (i.e. changing `VARCHAR` to `NVARCHAR` or `DATETIME` to `VARCHAR` etc.)
- You're ok with error/fault handling for batches rather than rows
- You're doing primarily point to point integrations that are unlikely to change or will only be needed temporarily.

BizTalk is well suited for real time messaging needs where:

- You're transferring messages between any two end points
- You need a centralized hub and/or ESB for message processing
- You need fine grained transformations of messages
- You need to work with more complicated looping file structures (i.e. not straight up CSV)
- You need to apply analyst manageable business rules
- You need to be able to easily swap out endpoints at run time
- You need more enhanced error/fault management for individual messages/rows
- You need enhanced B2B capabilities (EDI, HL7, SWIFT, trading partner management, acknowledgements)

Both can do the job of the other with a lot of extra work, but to see this, try to get SSIS to do a task that would require calling a stored procedure per row and have it do proper error handling/transformation of each row, and try to have BizTalk do a bulk ETL operation that requires minimal transformation.  Both can do either, but it will be painful.

Comment: individual Row data error handling is supported in SSIS https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/error-handling-in-data?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Yes, but it severely slows down processing.  SSIS *can* do it, but won't do it very well quickly and will likely end up requiring lots of custom code/logic that BizTalk will handle more fluidly.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer, no.

BizTalk Server and SSIS are different paradigms and are used to complement each other, not in opposition.  They are both part of the BizTalk Stack and are frequently used in the same app.

BizTalk is a messaging platform and app will tend to process one entity at a time.  SSIS is set based and works best for bulk table based operations.

Comment: They are not both of the BizTalk Stack, but they are used in the same Enterprise scenario's

Comment: Since SQL Server is a requirement for BizTalk Server, all of it's components are available in the BizTalk stack, just like any feature of Windows such as IIS.  Call it the Microsoft On Premise Integration Stack...which can also run on Azure.